# How can I perform conditional calculation in Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

I want to calculate pricing based on location, destination & weight.

For example, if a user wants to send a shipment from Austria to Ireland and the weight is up to 10 kg then the price will be $27 and if up to 20 kg then $29 and so on up to 50 kg.

I have From & To fields for location & destination and I have a repeating section which includes a weight field and at the end I have a calculation field.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to write conditional if/then calculations in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

1. `if <condition> then <true result> else <false result>`
2. `<condition> ? <true result> : <false result>`

For your specific example, lets assume you create a calculation outside your repeating section called `Total Weight` with the calculation `=Packages.Sum(Weight)` that sums up the weight of the items in the `Packages` repeating section.

You can then write the following calculation to based on your example:

`=if Location = "Austria" and Destination = "Ireland" then
    if Weight <= 10 then $27 else if Weight < 20 then $29 else ...
 else ...`

If you have a ton of options like this, I suspect this would be very difficult to work through.  It sounds like you want to be able to look up a value from a very long table of potential values.  Please provide feedback to this answer and I will be glad to refine my response.

Comment: Yes we need to set prices based on country to country, how did you end the calculation with else ... else ... form is not accepting that.

Comment: The ... was just placeholder for additional logic you may need to write for additional countries and weights.  How many different configurations do you expect?

Comment: I see, how do i end the logic as it is asking for else at the end, we need same configuration for up to 20 countries and weights are up to 10,20,30,40 & 50kg

Comment: You have to have an else value, so just make the value really big if you do not expect the else to ever be used.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to end the statement, it keep asking me to add else at the end, i tried different options but it doesn't work, can you give me a complete calculation please so i can add more countries, thanks.